# Ember.js - this.set() in ApplicationRoute not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase

I am trying to set a boolean variable whenever the user is logged in.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  isLoggedIn: false,

  init: function() {
      if (loggedIn) {
        this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
      } else {
        console.log(error)
        this.set('isLoggedIn', false);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However, on `this.set()` I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any ideas?

I figured that the best place to handle user session is in the `App.ApplicationRoute` since its the root of everything. Does this cause a problem?

UPDATED:
With feedback here is the current / full code.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  isLoggedIn: false,

  init: function() {
    this._super();

    auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(appRef, function(error, user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
      } else {
        console.log(error)
        this.set('isLoggedIn', false);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

So I left out my Firebase code previously because I didnt really think it relevant, but for the sake of tracking down the problem, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason has to do with the

```
this
```

being wrongly set in your firebasesimplelogin. The function you are using inside the constructor must be passed in a reference to 'this' of the outer context. The easiest way to do it is by changing the code of the function to this:

```
function(error, user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user)
    this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
  } else {
    console.log(error)
    this.set('isLoggedIn', false);
  }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Not really :).  The design of the JS language is screwed up when it comes to how the inner functions' this value is set. I have just had too much trouble with it in the past, so that's the first thing I check when I find an error message like 'undefined is not a function' or whatever..

Comment: Good call. I'm putting that one in my tool belt.

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first :)

As stated at the [Ember.js documenation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_init):

> NOTE: If you do override init for a framework class like Ember.View or Ember.ArrayController, **be sure to call this._super() in your init declaration**! If you don't, Ember may not have an opportunity to do important setup work, and you'll see strange behavior in your application.

Second, your `loggedIn` variable is not declared nor instantiated and therefore null as well as your `error` but I guess you just ripped out some code of your project to fiddle together a quick example, so if you do:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  isLoggedIn: false,

  init: function() {
      this._super(); // <-- call `this._super()` here

      if (loggedIn) {
        this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
      } else {
        console.log(error)
        this.set('isLoggedIn', false);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

everything should work as expected :)

Comment: So, first off, thanks for the answer! I forgot about `this._super()`. Second, I updated the question with the full code. I'm using Firebase and just removed it because I didnt think it relevant (good guess!) but I might as well add it in.

I tried what I have above but it still doesnt work. It'll log out `user` but returns the error on `this.set()`

Comment: just seen it yet, but with your updated code it all makes sense :) - it was a scoping issue :)